# Probability of right angle triangle froming from cutting stick

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose that you have a stick of lenght 1, for simplicity sake, and that you make two cuts at random. I know the probability of the cuts producing a triangle is of 25%; but my question is: if you make those two cuts, how likely will it be that you can produce a ***right angle*** triangle?

Comment: For a right triangle you must have $a^2+ b^2= c^2$.  Of course. since the stick has length 1, c= 1- a- b so $a^2+ b^2= (1- a- b)^2= 1+ a^2+ b^2- 2a- 2b$. That reduces to 2(a+ b)= 1.  If a and b are random what is the probability that a+ b= 1/2?

Comment: @user247327 There is a $2ab$ term missing.

Comment: Oops! Yes.  Thank you!

Comment: The probability of a right triangle will surely be $0$ (assuming the possible cuts are real number  lengths) since it is a one dimensional set inside the two dimensional sample space (as user247327's comment shows). Similarly, the probability of isosceles will be $0$ and scalene will be $1$. An interesting question to ask are the probabilities of acute vs. obtuse triangle, those will add to $1$ but neither will be $0$.